# Titanium multiple json item passed to php

Tags: javascript, php, json, titanium, appcelerator

Hi I was hoping to get a hand with Appecelator Titanium. I am trying to add multiple items to the a database from a app. I am using php and passing a json object.

Here is my js code:

```
var username = "testUser";
```

$.createBox_buttonWrapper.addEventListener('click', function(e){

```
Ti.API.info("NEW NAME" + $.createBox_textfield.value);
var boxName = "";
boxName = $.createBox_textfield.value;
var pin = "";
var privateBox = 0;
if ($.privateSwitch.value == true) {
    privateBox = 1;
    pin = $.createBox_pinTextField.value;
    Ti.API.info("PIN:" + $.createBox_pinTextField.value);
}
pin = pin.toString();
boxName = boxName.toString();

//minus the photo
var createBox_request = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function(){
        Ti.API.info("SEND");
        Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
        var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        for ( var data in obj ){
            if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(data) ){
                for ( var i in obj[data]){
                    var content = obj[data][i]['and'];
                    if ( content = "success" ){
                        alert("Box created!");//remove
                        //success window
                    }else{
                        alert("Error: ");

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    onError: function(){
        Ti.API.debug(e.error);
    }
});
createBox_request.open("POST","http://*****/app/createBox.php");
createBox_request.send( {data: {  "username_post":username,"boxName_post":boxName,"picturePath_post":"test","private_post":privateBox,"pin_post":pin} });
```

});
$.index.open();

Here is the php:

```
<?php
$data = isset($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data']: "";//brings in string
// {
//    "boxName" = boxName;
//    "picturePath_post" = testPath;
//    "pin_post" = 9133;
//    "private_post" = 1;
//    "username_post" = testUser;
//  }
$items = explode(";", $data);
for( $i = 0 ; $i < count($items) ; $i++ ){
    $start = strpos($items[$i],' = ');
    $string = substr($items[$i], $start);
    $string = substr($string, 3);
    $items[$i] = $string;
}
$boxName = $items[0]; //getting error here
$picPath = $items[1];
$pin = $items[2];
$private = $items[3];
$username = $items[4];
$username = contentCheck($username);
if($username != ""){
    $boxName = contentCheck($boxName);
    $picPath = contentCheck($picPath);
    $private = contentCheck($private);
    $pin = contentCheck($pin);
    $code = genCode();//generate unique code
    $lastDate = date("Y-m-d");
    $con = mysqli_connect("***","***","***","***");
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO ( code, title, owner, picturePath, rep, users, private, lastDate, creationDate) VALUES ( '$code','$boxName','$username','$picPath',0,0,$private,'$lastDate','$lastDate')");
    echo '{"results":[{"and":"success"}]}';
}else{
    //return false and get the app user to enter their username and password
    echo '{"results":[{"and":"error"}]}';
}
function contentCheck($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

I know my error is somewhere in the php. I marked it with a comment. What am I doing wrong? I am receiving a  on the this.response. So the php is causing an error. There is nothing in the error log.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and your error is...?

Comment: do     json_decode($data); and then access the data as an array. Its far too easy compared to the explode and manual elements hunt.

Answer (score 0):

You need use [json_decode](http://php.net//manual/es/function.json-decode.php):

```
$data = isset($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : "";
if($data != "")
{
   $data = json_decode($data);
   $boxName = $data->{'boxName_post'};
   $picPath = $data->{'picturePath_post'};
   $pin = $data->{'pin_post'};
   $private = $data->{'private_post'};
   $username = $data->{'username_post'};
   $username = contentCheck($username);
   if($username != "")
   {
      $boxName = contentCheck($boxName);
      $picPath = contentCheck($picPath);
      $private = contentCheck($private);
      $pin = contentCheck($pin);
      $code = genCode();//generate unique code
      $lastDate = date("Y-m-d");
      $con = mysqli_connect("***","***","***","***");
      mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO ( code, title, owner, picturePath, rep, users, private, lastDate, creationDate) VALUES ( '$code','$boxName','$username','$picPath',0,0,$private,'$lastDate','$lastDate')");
      echo '{"results":[{"and":"success"}]}';
   }
   else
   {
      echo '{"results":[{"and":"error"}]}';
   }
}
else
{
   echo '{"results":[{"and":"error"}]}';
}

function contentCheck($data){
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
```